# How to create an explicit formula of a function

Tags: functions

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable and nondecreasing function such that $\phi(x)=-1$ for $x<-1$, $\phi(x)=1$ for $x>1$, and $\phi^\prime(x)>0$ for $x\in(-1,1)$.

**Question**  How to find some explicit formulae for $\phi$?

Thank you for kind comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} {3 \over 2} ( 1-x^2), & |x| < 1 \\
0, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$,
and note that $f$ is continuous and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = 2$.

Let $\phi(x) = -1+\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$. We see that $\phi'(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Could you explain me how to choose $\phi(x)$?

Comment: You are given that $\phi$ is differentiable, do look what the requirements mean for $\phi'$. It must be zero for $|x| \ge 1$, positive elsewhere, and since $\phi$ changes from -1 to +1, we must have $\int_{-1}^1 \phi'(x)dx = 2$. I just picked the $f$ above to satisfy these conditions (and be continuous to guarantee differentiability) . Many other $f$ will do too, for example, a 'triangle' would do.

Comment: Dear copper.hat, I am grateful to you if you could give your comments on the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802541/elementary-properties-of-gradient-systems

Answer (score 1):

You can define $\phi$ in a [piecewise manner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) as long as you make sure to maintain differentiability, particularly at the boundary points of subdomains, i.e.

$$
\phi(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-1, & x\in(-\infty,-1) \\
h(x),  & x \in [-1, 1] \\
1, & x \in (1, +\infty)
\end{cases}
$$

If you choose $h(x)$ s.t. it is nondecreasing, differentiable, and satisfies certain conditions, which stand  for differentiability and continuity of $\phi$ at the boundary points $a=-1$ and $b = 1$. The conditions are:

- $\lim\limits_{x \to a^{+}} h(x) = -1 \quad$ — [right limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) of $h$ equals to $-1$ at the point $a = -1$,
- $\lim\limits_{x \to b^{-}} h(x) =  1 \quad$ — [left limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) of $h$ equals to $1$ at the point $b = 1$,
- $ \partial_{+}h(a) := \lim\limits_{x \to a^{+}} \dfrac{h(x) - h(a)}{x-a} =  0 \quad$ — [right derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_and_right_derivative) of $h$ equals to $0$ at the point $a = -1$,
- $ \partial_{-}h(b) := \lim\limits_{x \to b^{-}} \dfrac{h(b) - h(x)}{b-x} =  0 \quad$ — [left derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_and_right_derivative) of $h$ equals to $0$ at the point $b = 1$.

The last two conditions are actually extras as they will give you a **continuous derivative** of $\phi$.
I can image that one can come with a lot of versions of function $h$. For example, you can use [following function](http://fooplot.com/plot/82c8kq336j)
$$
h(x) :=  \operatorname{sgn}(x)\cdot \left( 1 - \mathrm{e}^\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}  \right),
$$

[image]
where $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = x/|x|$ is the *[signum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)* function.

Comment: Dear Vlad, I am grateful to you if you could give your comments on the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802541/elementary-properties-of-gradient-systems